# MapView in the Android 3.0 Honeycomb Preview AVD emulator?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-3.0-honeycomb

When I push my app to a Honeycomb AVD I get this:

```
Package com.myapp requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
```

Am I right in thinking this is because the Preview SDK only provides the AOSP SDK, and not the Google components?

Is there currently any way to test apps in the Honeycomb AVD that rely on MapView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the preview SDK doesn't include the Google Add-On, and the emulator doesn't have the necessary library.

However, the final SDK is now released and you should be able to create an AVD (emulator image) that contains the Maps shared library by installing the Google Add-On for Android 3.0.